# How to stop pandas value_counts from counting the header row

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, csv

Should be a really simple fix but I cant find the solution.

```
df = pd.read_csv(concat_Xenos, header=None, index_col=False)[0]
counts = df.value_counts()

print(counts)
```

This ^^ returns this:

```
M116_13331848_13109013339679.jpg     4
M116_13331848_13109013338679.jpg     4
M116_13331848_13109013358679.jpg     3
M116_13331848_13109013356679.jpg     3
M116_13331848_13109013362678.jpg     3
M116_13331848_13109013363678.jpg     2
Filename                             1
M116_13331848_13109013336679.jpg     1
```

How do I prevent the 'filename' header from being counted by the value_counts command?

I have tried playing aorund with the '*header=*' and '*index_col=*' parameters but that just return errors with every combo.

The head of the df (df.head()) is:

```
0                            Filename
1    M116_13331848_13109013315679.jpg
2    M116_13331848_13109013315679.jpg
3    M116_13331848_13109013315679.jpg
4    M116_13331848_13109013315679.jpg
```

Cheers,
R

Comment: Can you post the top of the original dataframe? e.g. via `df.head()`. This would help with debugging. But it looks like you have a header in your file that you are excluding via `header=None`. You might try deleting the `header=None` and then do `df["Filename"].value_counts()`

Comment: well you actually remove the Header with the `header=None` arg, what were you expecting?

Comment: @Michael the df.head() has been added to the bottom of the question above. But i made the suggested changes which worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Datanovice yes I understand that now! Thank you